# Set dataframe column value based count of values and group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The problem:

I have a basic python/pandas dataframe with a unit id ("Sarzs_no") and a column based on time of the day("Time_of_day", two values: day/night).

[image]

Unfortunately the time of day is unambiguos in the terms of one unit can contain both values (day and night). However it should contain only one.

I would like to have a solution for changing the time of day values for every unit, based on how many counts it has for day and night. If it has more counts for day than it should be set as day for all of its values, and vice versa.

[image]

I tried to make a formula on this problem:

```
def dayoftime(napszak_str):
    sarzs = row["Sarzs_no"]
    day = bfdataf[bfdataf["Sarzs_no"]==sarzs].groupby("Time_of_day").size()[0]
    night = bfdataf[bfdataf["Sarzs_no"]==sarzs].groupby("Time_of_day").size()[0]
    if day>=night:
        return "day"
    else:
        return "night"
```

...and then call it:

```
bfdataf["new_tod"] = bfdataf["Time_of_day"].apply(dayoftime)
```

But unfortunatelly I get "index out of bound" errors.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get count per groups by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), create `DataFrame` with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and last create column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = bfdataf.groupby(['Sarzs_no','Time_of_day']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
df = bfdataf.join(df, on='Sarzs_no')

bfdataf['new_tod'] = np.where(df['day'] >= df['night'], 'day', 'night')
```

Another solution is filter columns and get counts by `sum` per groups by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
days = (bfdataf['Time_of_day'] =='day').groupby(bfdataf['Sarzs_no']).transform('sum')
nights = (bfdataf['Time_of_day'] =='night').groupby(bfdataf['Sarzs_no']).transform('sum')

bfdataf['new_tod'] = np.where( days >= nights, 'day', 'night')
```

---

Another solution, thanks @Jon Clements is use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for helper `Series` and create new column by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = bfdataf.groupby(['Sarzs_no','Time_of_day']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).idxmax(axis=1)
bfdataf['new_tod'] = bfdataf['Sarzs_no'].map(s)
print (bfdataf)
   Sarzs_no Time_of_day new_tod
0    101/16         day     day
1    101/16         day     day
2    101/16         day     day
3    101/16         day     day
4    101/16         day     day
5    101/16       night     day
6    101/16       night     day
7    101/16       night     day
8    101/17       night   night
9    101/17       night   night
10   101/17       night   night
11   101/17       night   night
12   101/17       night   night
13   101/17       night   night
14   101/17       night   night
15   101/17       night   night
16   101/17       night   night
17   101/17       night   night
18   101/17         day   night
```

Comment: I wonder if instead of joining, you can keep the aggregates as a lookup table and apply that to the original... eg: `g = df.groupby(['a','b']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).apply('idxmax', axis=1)` and then do `df['new_tod'] = df.a.replace(g.index, g)` or similar...

Comment: @JonClements - Good idea, and then `map`, thank you.